# How to use numpy digitize for concatenated values that fall outside of range?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, vectorization, binary-search

I am trying to use `digitize` via the `numpy` module to assist in maintaining a gradebook. The idea is to input the total points earned by a student in a classroom such that the output is the corresponding letter grade. My attempt is below:

```
import numpy as np
from collections import OrderedDict

## letter grades and points at cusps of letter grades
letter_grades = np.array(['F', 'D-', 'D', 'D+', 'C-', 'C', 'C+', 'B-', 'B', 'B+', 'A-', 'A'])
point_edges = np.concatenate(np.linspace(101, 153, len(letter_grades)), 10**3)
point_edges[0] = 0

## each letter grade corresponds to point values within the two corresponding point edges
edge_pairs = np.array([('{} - {}'.format(point_edges[idx-1], point_edges[idx])) for idx in range(1, len(point_edges))])
criteria = OrderedDict(zip(letter_grades, edge_pairs))
# print(criteria)

## sample data (the top one works, the one below throws an error)
# point_scores = (0, 100, 100.9, 101, 101.1, 136)
point_scores = (0, 100, 100.9, 101, 101.1, 136, 146, 150, 152, 153, 154)

## use numpy to get result
indices = np.digitize(point_scores, point_edges)
final_grades = letter_grades[indices]

for point, grade in zip(point_scores, final_grades):
    print("\n .. {} POINTS :: {}\n".format(point, grade))
```

Running the above code outputs the following error:

```
IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12
```

I made `1000` the last element of `point_edges` so that any input values greater than 153 would output `'A'` (as seen in the `print(criteria)` statement commented out above. However, the algorithm only works for input values strictly less than 153. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`np.digizize` has a different numbering than `np.histogram` to indicate values that are outside of the boundaries:

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

> If values in x are beyond the bounds of bins, 0 or len(bins) is
>   returned as appropriate.

The index 12 in your case indicates that a value is above the given limits. If you want the last bin, this means index 11 in your case.
The first bin with index 0 are values below the lower boundary, index 1 is the first valid bin.